# Docker volume on Windows 2019 Host with Linux Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have an issue when running a Linux container with Windows 2019 and LCOW.

I can run a container with a simple docker run command

```
docker run --rm -name --restart=always --name map-1 -v c:/maps:/data registry.local/map-server
```

But when I try to do it with a docker compose file in Swarm, I get this error

```
invalid mount target, must be an absolute path: /data
```

Did someone already experience this issue, and found any workaround or something ? I just need to mount a single file from my host to the container.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're trying to mount this folder `c:/maps` to this `/data registry.local/map-server ` path inside of a container, right? Maybe try solution from this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255004/when-using-docker-option-mount-the-target-folder-is-seen-as-not-absolute-whil)

Comment: Also, which version of docker are you using?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, 
Yes I try to mount the folder c:\maps into /data in the container.  
I'm using docker 19.03.13 on Windows 2019.

Comment: The above solution is not working; getting this error : invalid mount target, must be an absolute path: //data

Comment: How about if you put the path on the host like this: `/c/maps` - note the forward slash before the drive name and no `:`

Comment: I didn t find any solutions for this, so I decide to write my own Windows container running this nodeJs app. A little bit more effort but now it works...